# Extended ASCII Character Conversion

Tags: python, type-conversion, ascii, extended-ascii

How can I convert Extended ASCII characters **such as**: "æ, ö or ç" into non-extended ASCII characters (a,o,c) using python? The way it works should be that if it takes "A, Æ ,Ä" as input, It returns A for all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/) might be of use to you.

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jun  8 2012, 05:36:09) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode("æ, ö or ç")
'ae, o or c'
```

Comment: Looks nice, but isn't there any way to do this in python 2? But this will do to in case there isn't.

Comment: odd, I tried but didn't work. Thanks I'll use the python 3 CODE

Comment: 8 years later I can say that this aged well ;)